# how to convert string[][] to double[][] or int[][] in C#

Tags: c#, string, type-conversion

I have a two dimensional string array and wants to convert in `double` or `int` for classficaton.

I tried `codification` but it gives the following error, so I need an alternate method.

> Attempted to read or write protected memory. This is often an indication that other memory is corrupt.

For example,

```
string[] columnNames = { "Outlook", "Temperature", "Humidity", "Wind", "PlayTennis" };

string[][] data = {
    new string[] { "Sunny", "Hot", "High", "Weak", "No" },
    new string[] { "Sunny", "Hot", "High", "Strong", "No" },
    new string[] { "Overcast", "Hot", "High", "Weak", "Yes" },
    new string[] { "Rain", "Mild", "High", "Weak", "Yes" },
    new string[] { "Rain", "Cool", "Normal", "Weak", "Yes" },
    new string[] { "Rain", "Cool", "Normal", "Strong", "No" },
    new string[] { "Overcast", "Cool", "Normal", "Strong", "Yes" },
    new string[] { "Sunny", "Mild", "High", "Weak", "No" },
    new string[] { "Sunny", "Cool", "Normal", "Weak", "Yes" },
    new string[] {  "Rain", "Mild", "Normal", "Weak", "Yes" },
    new string[] {  "Sunny", "Mild", "Normal", "Strong", "Yes" },
    new string[] {  "Overcast", "Mild", "High", "Strong", "Yes" },
    new string[] {  "Overcast", "Hot", "Normal", "Weak", "Yes" },
    new string[] {  "Rain", "Mild", "High", "Strong", "No" },
};

// Create a new codification codebook to
// convert strings into discrete symbols
Codification codebook = new Codification(columnNames, data);

// Extract input and output pairs to train
int[][] symbols = codebook.Transform(data);
int[][] inputs = symbols.Get(null, 0, -1); // Gets all rows, from 0 to the last (but not the last)
int[] outputs = symbols.GetColumn(-1);     // Gets only the last column
```

i also tried,

```
 double[][] double_data = data.Select(x => x.Select(str => Convert.ToDouble(str)).ToArray()).ToArray();
```

and got the same exception.how to resolve it.

Comment: It seems that there is some problem inside a `Codification` class. Your last code section will fail because you can't convert `"Sunny"` to `double.` The error will be: `Input string was not in a correct format.`,

Comment: Can you show the code for `codebook.Transform(data);`?

Comment: Just a note, what you have is a jagged array (array of arrays) , not a two dimensional one. Two dimensions are declared as `datatype[sizeX, sizeY]`

Comment: @AleksandrIvanov then is there any way to classfy it without uing codification? i got this code from http://accord-framework.net/docs/html/T_Accord_MachineLearning_Bayes_NaiveBayes.htm

Comment: @AsadAli tranform is a builtin operation of accord.net.

Comment: @pinkfloydx33 oh  yes Thank you. is it possible to convert a jagged array